# has_one, :through => model VS simple method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I have some issues using `has_one, through => model`. The best is to show you my case.

```
class Category
  has_many :articles
end

class Article
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :category
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :article
  has_one :category, :through => :articles
end
```

Everthing works fine. I can do `comment.category`. The problem is when I create a new comment and set up its article, I have so save the comment to make the association works. Example :

```
 >> comment = Comment.new
 >> comment.article = Article.last
 >> comment.category
     -> nil
 >> comment.article.category
     -> the category
 >> comment.save
 >> comment.category
     -> nil
 >> comment.reload
 >> comment.category
     -> the category
```

`has_one, through => model` anyway do not set up, build constructor and create method. So, I want to replace my comment model by :

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :article
  def category
    article.category
  end
end
```

Sounds a good idea ?

Comment: anyone? no one have a good opinions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your idea. I can't see many situations in which `has_one :category, :through => :articles` would be the obvious better choice (unless eager-loading with `Comment.all(:include => :category)` ).

A hint on `delegate`:

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :article
  delegate :category, :to => :article
```

A different approach:

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :article
  has_one :category, :through => :article

  def category_with_delegation
    new_record? ? article.try(:category) : category_without_delegation
  end

  alias_method_chain :category, :delegation
```

Comment: some more information to `alias_method_chain` can be found [here](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/03/06/alias_method_chain-in-models/)

Comment: I feel like this is what Rails should be doing by default... Instead of just always querying the database, go through the object that's in memory already!

Answer (score 2):

Try to make changes in your Category class like this:

```
class Category
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments, :through => :articles
end
```

Comment: sorry, misspelled it on stakeoverflow. Not the problem on my real application.